# Unable to Unpivot in MS Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I am unable to unpivot this table. I keep getting an error that two tables don't exist. I am using  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Here are the errors.

```
type            Small_Bags         Large_Bags
conventional    8603.6201171875     93.25
conventional    9408.0703125        97.4899978637695
conventional    8042.2099609375     103.139999389648
conventional    5677.39990234375    133.759994506836
conventional    5986.259765625      197.690002441406
conventional    6556.47021484375    127.440002441406
```

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 74
Invalid column name 'Small_Bags'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 74
Invalid column name 'Large_Bags'

```
select type,Small_Bags,Large_Bags from avocado
unpivot
(
    amount 
    for category in (Small_Bags,Large_Bags)
) as unpivotexample
```

Comment: **1.** `MS-SQL` or `MySQL`? - Please tag the correct DBMS **2.** Please provide the sample input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio implies SQL Server I  believe. Your pivot converts `Small_Bags,Large_Bags` columns into  `category, amount`  columns. So

```
select type, category, amount 
from avocado
unpivot
(
    amount 
    for category in (Small_Bags,Large_Bags)
) as unpivotexample
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1d637f60238db67c6b49c737d66296e4)